# Visual Studio 2013 Incremental Search Behavior Changed

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, incremental-search

In Visual Studio 2010, the behavior of incremental search was:

1. Ctrl+I
2. Type your search characters
3. Click somewhere else to quit incremental search
4. To search again *using the same search*: Ctrl+I, Ctrl+I

In Visual Studio 2013, the behavior of repeating incremental search is removed:

1. Ctrl+I
2. The search box opens
3. If you want to repeat the previous incremental search, hitting Ctrl+I works as Tab since the search box has the keyboard focus, bringing up the previous text from a Ctrl+F search.

Is there a way to go back to the Visual Studio 2010 way of handling repeated incremental searches? I.e., not bringing up the search box.

Thanks!
Peter, the keyboard jockey